# How to replace a character sequence with regex?

Tags: java, regex, xml, hex

I need to remove invalid characters references in xml, that is, if in my xml input has something like

```
&#x1A;
```

must be removed or replaced. Codes to remove invalid characters in XML does not serve as the input is a stream that has already transformed these characters in numerical references. I know the invalid xml characters are hexadecimal numbers from 20, but I am not knowing how to make the regular expression. I would like to code in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
// Init replacement map
Map<Matcher, String> replacementMap = new HashMap<Matcher, String>() {
    {
       // Put your replacement rules here...
       put(m("regex1"), "replacement1");
       put(m("regex2"), "replacement2");
       // ...
    }

    // Helper method for quickly creating a matcher and improve code readability
    private Matcher m(String regex) {
        return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("");
    }
};

// Load source string
String source = loadSourceString();

// Perform replacements
for(Map.Entry<Matcher, String> e: replacementMap.entrySet()) {
    e.getKey().reset(source).replaceAll(e.getValue());
}
```

You first create a map of your replacements then load into a string the text you want to change. We avoid the pattern compilation overhead by storing `Matcher` instances in front of replacement strings.

Here are some examples of replacement rules:

- `put(m("&x#[^;]{2};"), "")`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This is the most generic approach. It removes any character sequence.

- `put(m("&x#[2-9A-F][\dA-F];"), "BAZ")`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This approach replaces any character sequence in the hexadecimal range [20-FF] with `BAZ`.

- `put(m("&x#.F;"), "FOO")`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This one replaces any character sequence ending with `F` with `FOO`.